# Is tf2onnx compatible with Tensorflow saved_models produced by Google Cloud Platform (e.g., BQML model export)?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, onnx, tf2onnx

I am attempting to use the [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx) package and CLI tool to automatically convert a Tensorflow saved_model to ONNX.  I was able to do this successfully using a basic model linked in [this tutorial](https://christianjmills.com/posts/tensorflow-savedmodel-to-onnx-tutorial/); however, I have been unable to convert models produced by GCP BigQueryML, such as this [Fraud Detection model](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/frauddetection-using-console#5).

All attempts on this and other models exported from BQML fail with the error `ValueError: Failed to import metagraph, check error log for more info.`.

Is it possible to convert BQML models to ONNX?

- Python 3.9.16
- tensorflow-cpu 2.15.0
- tf2onnx 1.15.1

[image: file structure of fraud detection model]

Full stack trace:

```
(vertex-pocs) hrrt@M-C02DM10ZMD6R model % python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model cc-defaults --output onnx/cc-defaults.onnx --verbose     
2023-12-28 14:21:36.922146: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/runpy.py:127: RuntimeWarning: 'tf2onnx.convert' found in sys.modules after import of package 'tf2onnx', but prior to execution of 'tf2onnx.convert'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
2023-12-28 14:21:40,108 - WARNING - tf2onnx.tf_loader: '--tag' not specified for saved_model. Using --tag serve
2023-12-28 14:21:40,490 - INFO - tf2onnx.tf_loader: Signatures found in model: [serving_default].
2023-12-28 14:21:40,490 - WARNING - tf2onnx.tf_loader: '--signature_def' not specified, using first signature: serving_default
2023-12-28 14:21:40,490 - INFO - tf2onnx.tf_loader: Output names: ['default_payment_next_month_probs', 'default_payment_next_month_values', 'predicted_default_payment_next_month']
2023-12-28 14:21:40,490 - WARNING - tf2onnx.tf_loader: Could not search for non-variable resources. Concrete function internal representation may have changed.
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing variables.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
This operation is not supported when eager execution is enabled.
2023-12-28 14:21:40,497 - WARNING - tensorflow: Issue encountered when serializing variables.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
This operation is not supported when eager execution is enabled.
WARNING:tensorflow:Issue encountered when serializing trainable_variables.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
This operation is not supported when eager execution is enabled.
2023-12-28 14:21:40,497 - WARNING - tensorflow: Issue encountered when serializing trainable_variables.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef. Note this is a warning and probably safe to ignore.
This operation is not supported when eager execution is enabled.
2023-12-28 14:21:40.500445: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:75] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0 (Note: TensorFlow was not compiled with CUDA or ROCm support)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/convert.py", line 714, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/convert.py", line 242, in main
    graph_def, inputs, outputs, initialized_tables, tensors_to_rename = tf_loader.from_saved_model(
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 615, in from_saved_model
    _from_saved_model_v2(model_path, input_names, output_names,
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 599, in _from_saved_model_v2
    frozen_graph, initialized_tables = from_trackable(imported, concrete_func, inputs, outputs, large_model)
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 222, in from_trackable
    raise e
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 218, in from_trackable
    frozen_graph = from_function(concrete_func, inputs, outputs, large_model)
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 277, in from_function
    raise e
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf2onnx/tf_loader.py", line 270, in from_function
    frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(func, lower_control_flow=False, aggressive_inlining=True)
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 1164, in convert_variables_to_constants_v2
    converter_data = _FunctionConverterDataInEager(
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 827, in __init__
    graph_def = _run_inline_graph_optimization(func, lower_control_flow,
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 1062, in _run_inline_graph_optimization
    return tf_optimizer.OptimizeGraph(config, meta_graph)
  File "/Users/hrrt/.pyenv/versions/vertex-pocs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/grappler/tf_optimizer.py", line 76, in OptimizeGraph
    out_graph = optimize_method(
ValueError: Failed to import metagraph, check error log for more info.
```